Is the resurrection of righteous and wicked at the same time?, or two separate events separated by a millenium time period?
How can classical or dispensational premillenial models of endtimes which place the resurrection of the righteous at the start of the millenium and the resurrection of the wicked at the end of the millenium be supported in the light of scriptures such as the following?

John 5:28-29 NIV [28] “Do not be amazed at this, for a time is coming
when all who are in their graves will hear his voice [29] and come
out---those who have done what is good will rise to live, and those
who have done what is evil will rise to be condemned.
1 Thessalonians 4:16 NIV [16] For the Lord himself will come down from
heaven, with a loud command, with the voice of the archangel and with
the trumpet call of God, and the dead in Christ will rise first.

The shout of Christ calling all to resurrection surely cannot continue over a millenium period?

Acts 24:15 NIV [15] and I have the same hope in God as these men
themselves have, that there will be a resurrection of both the
righteous and the wicked.

Paul talks about the resurrection of wicked and righteous as a resurrection (singular tense) showing his theology is the wicked and righteous are resurrected at the same time one being caught up (raptured) in the air with receipt of a glorified body to be assembled together in one with Christ at his coming and the other raised in their unchanged body of sin to face judgement.

It always seems to take an eternity, but once it's time, usually premium boards first ;-).

Let me summarize the Bible references to the two resurrections.

In these references, the two resurrections of the righteous and the wicked are mentioned but their timing, whether separate or simultaneous is not stated.  John 5:28, 29, Dan 12:2, Acts 24:15, Heb 11:35.  However, the very fact that two resurrections are mentioned at all, means that they are likely separate events (as distinct from a single general resurrection of all people).

It is only in Rev 20:4-6 that we discover that the two resurrections of the righteous and wicked are separated by 1000 years:



I saw thrones on which were seated those who had been given authority
to judge. And I saw the souls of those who had been beheaded because
of their testimony about Jesus and because of the word of God. They a
had not worshiped the beast or its image and had not received its mark
on their foreheads or their hands. They came to life and reigned with
Christ a thousand years. (The rest of the dead did not come to life
until the thousand years were ended.) This is the first resurrection.
Blessed and holy are those who share in the first resurrection. The
second death has no power over them, but they will be priests of God
and of Christ and will reign with him for a thousand years.

[Note:  Based on John 3 about being born again and the above passage, it has been said that if a person is born twice they only die once; but if one is born once, they die twice.]

It is not clear, but it appears that there might be a "special resurrection" of some who were responsible for murdering/executing Christ as recorded in Rev 1:7 when Jesus returns the second time:


“Look, he is coming with the clouds,” and “every eye will see him,
even those who pierced him”; and all peoples on earth “will mourn
because of him.” So shall it be! Amen.

However, this is a debated point I do not wish to make too much of it.  For example, it might be that Rev 1:7 is discussing the wicked dead seeing Jesus after the 1000 years.  However, this might be the subject of another question.

1 Thess 4:15-17 -


According to the Lord’s word, we tell you that we who are still alive,
who are left until the coming of the Lord, will certainly not precede
those who have fallen asleep. For the Lord himself will come down from
heaven, with a loud command, with the voice of the archangel and with
the trumpet call of God, and the dead in Christ will rise first. After
that, we who are still alive and are left will be caught up together
with them in the clouds to meet the Lord in the air. And so we will be
with the Lord forever.

Note that is NOT discussing the resurrection of the wicked, only the righteous - the "rising" of the righteous is to meet the Lord in the air.  The wicked are not discussed.

Seems like there's a judgment when Jesus comes in Matthew 24:48-51. "But if that wicked servant says to himself, ‘My master is delayed,’ and begins to beat his fellow servants and eats and drinks with drunkards, the master of that servant will come on a day when he does not expect him and at an hour he does not know and will cut him in pieces and put him with the hypocrites. In that place there will be weeping and gnashing of teeth." (ESV) Surely this doesn't occur during or after the Great Tribulation, right?

@Dieter - you appear to be confusing different sets of events - the great tribulation occurs before Jesus second coming as per Matt 24:29-31

Perhaps I'm confused. Yes, the Great Tribulation occurs before the second coming of Jesus, but the terms "wicked servant," a delayed master, "beats his fellow servants," and an unexpected day and time seem to apply to before the Great Tribulation and not at the second coming of Jesus which follows.

@Dieter - that should be the subject of another question.

@Dottard – your point #3 – I understand there is no “special resurrection”. Reason: Rev 1:7 is a direct quote of Daniel 7:13 and Zech 12:10. The latter says, “the house of David” (Jews) and “those living in Jerusalem” (Jews) will see “Me (Yahweh) whom they have pierced” and mourn. So, Rev 1:7 simply says, all people (Gentiles as well as the Jews who pierced Him) in the world living at that time will see Jesus and mourn.

@NepheshRoi - that is a reasonable interpretation; but as stated above, I do not want to make too much of this because it is not the prime subject of the question.

I agree with you, Dottard.

When Revelation's information about the resurrection of the dead is combined with what Jesus said in his parable of the angels sent to reap out the weeds from the field of good wheat, the answer presents itself:
There is one harvest, with two reapings - the second one immediately after the first.
This clears everything up, but, of course, those who believe in the interpretation of prophecy that there will be a 'rapture' of believers from Earth, to take them away from a time of tribulation, have a time-gap between both events, and they do not accept that there can be one harvest, with two reapings, with no time gap. That is an a-millennial interpretation.
I am not going to argue the a-millennial case here, but would simply encourage those interested to read Matthew 13:24-30, which deals with "the time of harvest" and a reaping by angels of the tares (weeds) for burning. Then please read Revelation 14:16-17 where a first reaping precedes the one immediately following (that of the fruit of the earth, for the wrath of God.)
Different symbolisms are used (e.g. weeds in one, grapes in the other). There are reasons for that, but it remains clear that, at the end, reaping happens twice, with no time gap indicated, therefore one harvest with two reapings. That fits with Jesus' parable in Matthew 13:24-30.
Whether a six-year period of tribulation, or a one-thousand-year period of millennium is in view, neither fits with the texts used by the O.P. and the two I have given here. Here is a sample from a book that delves deeply into this very matter as depicted in Revelation:

"That another - and distinct - angel of judgment came out of the
temple which is in heaven, after 'the earth was reaped', Revelation
14:16; and reaped by one like unto the Son of man as opposed to
angels; and that this other angel had in his hand - yet to be employed; another sharp sickle, of the same kind as that with which one like unto the Son of man had already reaped the firstfruits, argues beyond
all reasonable doubt another, a further reaping, even in that same
day of the Lord." The Revelation of Jesus Christ, John Metcalfe, p.
406 [bold emphasis mine]
http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

This subject is so complex, a book such as the one I have quoted from, really needs to be examined carefully to arrive at a conclusion.

This is certainly a hard question, but many people take verses out of context. For example, look at the resurrection described in Daniel 12:2, which sounds simultaneous, but in the parable of the wheat and the tares, the tares are harvested first, and in Revelation 20:4-6, blessed are those in the first resurrection. I believe it all fits together, but one must not try to squeeze them into a preconceived doctrine (i.e. biazogesis).

@Dieter Yes, lots of Bible portions need to be put together to get a complete picture. I only used two portions. The book I quote from takes  many pages and other texts to build up its case. This is why Qs like this can never be answered properly on Stack Hermeneutics. But, hopefully, some fresh points can be made to let readers start thinking along different lines, as an antidote to 'biazogesis'. (Love that word you use!)

Yes, exactly! In college, I read Dwight Pentecost's book, Things To Come and was confused and frustrated at the end. Most of the theories presented dealt with the verses that presented a problem by simply ignoring them. Glad you like biazogesis! :-) Reminds me of the founder of a company I once worked for. He lauded people who, when encountering a problem where something didn't fit, just grabbed "a bigger hammer." I'd hate to think of him doing a jigsaw puzzle or biblical hermeneutics! :o

In Rev 20:5 greek word for ‘first- protos’ means first with respect to timing or position. Some of the translations do use ‘better’ resurrection i.e. the righteous receiving glorified bodies. Think incorrect doctrine to use this to argue there must be more than one resurrection.

@Mungo,  to be clear; I understand that the time of great tribulation comes to a sudden, unexpected end with Christ appearing in glory with hosts from heaven. The bodies of the dead saints are raised as glorified bodies to join with their spirit part, the faithful saints still on Earth are taken up to then join them, and then immediately comes the resurrection of all the other dead. There's no time gap; one harvest, two reapings, at the end of the Day of the Lord.

@Anne agree completely-i would add I think many theologians bring complexity and error into their end time teaching by attaching too much importance to Rev20:1-6. It is after all only 1 witness in a book of visions unsupported by Jesus, Paul, the OT and the apostles apart from John. If the doctrine is does not fit with scripture John 5 and Acts 24 then the doctrine is questionable. If this scripture was removed from the bible we would all have a different view of end times. Most other scriptures being removed would not have any impact since there are 2 or 3 witnesses

@Mungo  No need to remove Rev.20:1-6 (perish the very thought!) It fits in perfectly with all the other related texts as explained in the book I quoted from (link at the end of my answer). Metcalfe’s explanation is on pp. 535 to 614. If you are prepared to study 80 pages of in-depth exposition, you will see why Rev.20:1-6 is vital to a correct understanding.

@Anne Agree all scripture is God breathed - I was just trying to make the point that doctrine should flow out of harmony with the rest of scripture- I have said way too much & will read your suggestion Thankyou

@Mungo I agree with the balance you are suggesting. To me, one of the main arguments against extravagant claims of a 'millenium' after the return of the Lord is that it completely contradicts the parables of Jesus and their crystal clear urgency and immediacy of the final judgment, followed by glory or damnation.

@Nigel J Amen to that point

I believe @Dottard has provided a good answer.  Here is my take on the timeline:

Believers, in this age of God's grace (Eph 3:2), are spiritually "in Christ" now and are eternally secured upon having faith alone.

When the last believer believes and 'fills' the body of Christ (when the fulness of the Gentiles has come in), Christ will return "in the clouds". Those who are "dead in Christ" are caught up with Christ first with their new glorified bodies.

Those who are "alive and remain" in Christ are caught up in the clouds next with their new glorified bodies.

The tribulation then begins and the tribulation saints (the martyred 144k), along with all of believing Israel, are resurrected at the end of the tribulation.  This would include Peter and the 11, the "little flock", and all others who become believers during the tribulation and "endured unto the end" of it (refusing "the mark").

Christ then physically returns to earth for His millennial reign, (while Satan is bound, later released "for a season", gathers his armies, attacks Christ and Jerusalem, but swiftly defeated at Armageddon).

The resurrection of any dead millennial "just" and all unjust occurs (after Armageddon) for the "White Throne Judgement", where they are found to be in the Book of Life or not.

The unjust are cast into the lake of fire and everyone else will enter the new heaven and new earth.


This is all certainly open for debate, but I will admit that I do not know when the 'Judgement Seat of Christ' (not to be confused with the White Throne Judgement) will occur for the church, the body of Christ.  This is when the gifting of rewards to the church, the body of Christ, will occur, and where salvation is still secured "yet so as by fire", regardless of any "loss of reward".  I suspect this is shortly after the time that we are gifted our glorified bodies and are "in the clouds" with the entire church, the body of Christ.
Thankfully, by God's grace, salvation today is not dependent upon our own righteousness, nor on the accuracy of our knowledge in eschatology!

I'm in general agreement, Mark, but I wonder how much time separates your 2 and 3 above (10 minutes?) and why it should make any noticeable difference. There also seems to be a physical removal of all who give offense at the end of the tribulation before the millennium starts. Finally, I've noticed that there's a gathering from one end of heaven(s) to the other, which is different from one end of the earth to the other. Any thoughts on these questions?

@Dieter Hello Dieter! I cannot find any reason to believe there will be much of, if any, delay from the "fulness of the Gentile" body of believers, to when Christ returns in the clouds to gather that body. I think you are correct regarding the "removal" of the 'offended' also. I can't find justification scripturally to believe that those who did not endure would enter the coming earthly kingdom, unless...the "kingdom" does not fill the entirety of earth. I believe that is a very real possibility. I believe the "gathering" of heaven (us) and earth (Israel) is the "fullness of times" (Eph 1:10).

Mark, I try not avoid categorizing or forcing anything into the scriptures (aka biázōgesis), but I try to observe the patterns in scripture reveal themselves. I look to the prophecies in the tanakh that deal with the first coming of Jesus as a model of what to expect regarding the harpazo and the second coming. Some are very subtle indeed! Regarding the angels gathering the elect from the corners of the heavens, I envision believers scattered across the heavens in wildly exciting exploration, discoveries, discussions, and fellowship! Gathering them all won't be a trivial task.

It sounds like a good approach, @Dieter!

I am answering to present an alternate view to that presented.
The Amillenial view of end times regards the millennium as being a symbolic long period of time in the church age that the devil is locked up. The devil is released from prison at the end of the millennium and I think probably close to the end of the tribulation since it fits with the pattern of increasing evil in the tribulation and is just before the End ushered in by Christ’s return. The millennium is also a period of time where the saints rule and reign with Christ, healing the sick, winning the lost, making disciples and establishing the kingdom of God upon this world by being good ambassadors of Christ. It is important to establish how the devil being cast out of heaven fits into the sequence of bible events. When was Satan cast out of heaven?

Ezekiel 28:11
The word of the Lord came to me: 12 “Son of man, take up a lament concerning the king of Tyre and say
to him: ‘This is what the Sovereign Lord says:
“ ‘You were the seal of perfection, full of wisdom and perfect in beauty. 13 You were in Eden, the garden of God; ....
14 You were anointed as a guardian cherub, for so I ordained you.You were on the holy mount of God; you walked among the fiery stones. 15 You were blameless in your ways from the day you were created
till wickedness was found in you... and you sinned.
So I drove you in disgrace from the mount of God,
and I expelled you, guardian cherub, from among the fiery stones. 17 Your heart became proud on account of your beauty,
and you corrupted your wisdom because of your splendor.
So I threw you to the earth; I made a spectacle of you before kings.


Isaiah 14:12
How you have fallen from heaven, morning star, son of the dawn!
You have been cast down to the earth, you who once laid low the nations! 13 You said in your heart, “I will ascend to the heavens;
I will raise my throne above the stars of God;
I will sit enthroned on the mount of assembly, on the utmost heights of Mount Zaphon. 14 I will ascend above the tops of the clouds; I will make myself like the Most High.”
15 But you are brought down to the realm of the dead, to the depths of the pit.

This casting out of Satan did not occur in ages past. Jesus’s statement in John 12 fixes the time at which this happened was at Calvary. The legal basis for the devil being cast out was the finished work of Christ at Calvary.

John 12:31
Now is the time for judgment on this world; now the prince of this world will be driven out. 32 And I, when I am lifted up from the earth, will draw all people to myself.” 33 He said this to show the kind of death he was going to die.

This is further affirmed by Jesus’s prophetic words in Luke 10:18 where Jesus said he saw Satan fall like lightning from heaven.
Following Jesus’s death at Calvary he entered the strongman’s house and, He bound Satan, released his captives and took the keys of hell and the grave away from him.

Matthew 12:29
Or again, how can anyone enter a strong man’s house and carry off his possessions unless he first ties up the strong man? Then he can plunder his house.


Luke 11:21
When a strong man, fully armed, guards his own house, his possessions are safe. 22 But when someone stronger attacks and overpowers him, he takes away the armor in which the man trusted and divides up his plunder.


Revelation 1:18
I am He who lives, and was dead, and behold, I am alive forevermore. Amen. And I have the keys of Hades and of Death


Ephesians 4:11
When he ascended on high, he led captivity captive and gave gifts to his people.” 9 (What does “he ascended” mean except that he also descended to the lower, earthly regions? 10 He who descended is the very one who ascended higher than all the heavens, in order to fill the whole universe.)


Colossians 2:15
He disarmed the rulers and authorities and put them to open shame, by triumphing over them in him


Hebrews 2:14
Inasmuch then as the children have partaken of flesh and blood, He Himself likewise shared in the same, that through death He might destroy him who had the power of death, that is, the devil,15 and release those who through fear of death were all their lifetime subject to bondage.

Destroy in Hebrews 2:14 is the Greek word ‘καταργέω’ which can be translated “to render inactive,”“to condemn to inactivity”, “to put out of use” ,“to destroy” or “to remove from the sphere of activity” [Kittel]. This scripture together with Matthew 12:29 indicates that it is likely that Jesus entered the devils house and bound the strongman (devil) following his death and resurrection.
This is linked to Ephesians 4:11 when he led captivity captive and released hostages. We know Jesus took the keys of hell and the grave from the devil [Revelation 1:18]
The King of the bottomless pit ‘Apollyon’ could be another name for the devil. [Revelation 9:11]
Since Christ entered the devils house and bound him to release his captives. The captives are likely to be ‘the righteous dead Jews from paradise, ‘Abrahams bosom’ who like Abraham were made righteous through faith on a system of credit (Romans 4:3 accredited with righteousness through faith), but since the blood of Christ was not shed could not go to heaven, but had to stay in paradise a place of waiting for the righteous dead Jews, and thereafter were taken with Christ to heaven once his blood was shed at Calvary. Hebrews 9:26 says Jesus entered the Holy of Holy’s with his blood once for all time in the fullness of time. So this blood he shed paid for the forgiveness and sin of the Jew in OT period as well as any person saved in NT period i.e. salvation of all people for all time.

Revelation 20:1
Then I saw an angel coming down from heaven, having the key to the bottomless pit and a great chain in his hand.2 He laid hold of the dragon, that serpent of old, who is the Devil and Satan, and bound him for a thousand years; 3 and he cast him into the bottomless pit, and shut him up, and set a seal on him, so that he should deceive the nations no more till the thousand years were finished. But after these things he must be released for a little while.

At Calvary Jesus bound Satan and he was cast into the pit. During the church age Satan has ruled the hosts of darkness from the pit.

Revelation 9:11
And they had as king over them the angel of the bottomless pit, whose name in Hebrew is Abaddon, but in Greek he has the name Apollyon.

The devil therefore rules the hosts of hell from the pit. The devil is not omni-present and it is not rational to use the scripture that Satan is like a roaring lion seeking whom he may devour as proof that he is not in prison, since with billions of people on the earth he does not personally attack every Christian. I believe he has an upside down pyramid structure and his minions, principalities, powers, wicked spirits in high places, demon spirits carry out his will from the pit.
The millenium period is therefore just a symbolic long period of time in the church age between the first and second coming of Christ when the devil is bound.
If this sequence is accepted then the next event in this time period we live in is the 7 trumpets sounding, 7 bowels of wrath being poured out and 7 seals being opened. We see in Revelation a marking of the righteous and the wicked and we see 7 stages of increased demonic activity which will culminate in the devil himself being released from prison a short period before the second coming of Christ. This is what will accelerate the time of tribulation on the earth. As the sinfulness and rebellion of the wicked increases on the earth, increasing numbers of demons are released from hell upon the earth (e.g. Rev.9:3), and the point is reached where the devil is released from prison.
It is important to understand that for every bowel of wrath, there is a seal and a trumpet, so the glory upon the church increases to match the increasing darkness. The period of tribulation begins and the devil gathers to himself an army at Jerusalem (Armageddon), and at some point the Father calls time, Christ returns and the End takes place. I believe the trumpets are to call God’s people to attention to receive by faith the ministries, mantles and annointings that He is making available to His people at this time.
It is really important to prepare the Church for the next event it will need to face i.e. not rapture to heaven but the release of Satan from the pit.

Revelation 21:7
When the thousand years are over, Satan will be released from his prison 8 and will go out to deceive the nations in the four corners of the earth—Gog and Magog—and to gather them for battle.

The Church Age is brought to an "end" by the glorious return of Jesus as King of Kings and Lord of Lords (Rev 19:11-16).
At His return there is resurrection of the righteous and rapture to join Christ in his army, that immediately defeats the devil & his army. The wicked are then raised in their bodies of sin to face the White throne Judgement, and the righteous the Bhema judgement that rewards believers for fruit with motives that pass the test of fire. The wicked are cast in the Lake of fire with the devil and his angels, and the righteous are ushered into eternal life in the new heavens and new earth.

If Jesus is correct, the righteous (those who believe in Him) will rise on the last day:
[Jhn 6:39-40, 44, 54 KJV] 39 And this is the Father's will which hath sent me, that of all which he hath given me I should lose nothing, but should raise it up again at the last day. 40 And this is the will of him that sent me, that every one which seeth the Son, and believeth on him, may have everlasting life: and I will raise him up at the last day. ... 44 No man can come to me, except the Father which hath sent me draw him: and I will raise him up at the last day. ... 54 Whoso eateth my flesh, and drinketh my blood, hath eternal life; and I will raise him up at the last day.
Presumably this is the same day the unrighteous are resurrected, as it is the day that they are judged: [Jhn 12:48 KJV] 48 He that rejecteth me, and receiveth not my words, hath one that judgeth him: the word that I have spoken, the same shall judge him in the last day.
This fits well with the parable of the wheat and the tares, where the harvest and the burning of the weeds both occur at harvest time.

The Gospels appear to not separate the time. For example, Luke 19 says:

22 “The time came when the beggar died and the angels carried him to
Abraham’s side. The rich man also died and was buried. 23 In Hades,
where he was in torment, he looked up and saw Abraham far away, with
Lazarus by his side. 24 So he called to him, ‘Father Abraham, have
pity on me and send Lazarus to dip the tip of his finger in water and
cool my tongue, because I am in agony in this fire.’
25 “But Abraham replied, ‘Son, remember that in your lifetime you
received your good things, while Lazarus received bad things, but now
he is comforted here and you are in agony. 26 And besides all this,
between us and you a great chasm has been set in place, so that those
who want to go from here to you cannot, nor can anyone cross over from
there to us.’
27 “He answered, ‘Then I beg you, father, send Lazarus to my family,
28 for I have five brothers. Let him warn them, so that they will not
also come to this place of torment
Luke 19

We can read above both men were sent to their deed determined destination quite promptly and both men dwelt at the same time in heaven vs hell. We can read how the rich man was in hell while his family on earth were still living.

The question was about resurrection, not about going to heaven or hell. And Luke 19 is a parable, a story made up to illustrate a point, not a literal event.

Hi @Dhammadhatu, Ray is actually right - Luke 19 has been traditionally understood to be a parable that Jesus told for illustrative purposes. If you know of any commentators who understand it to be a historic account, please cite them in your answer so that readers can understand where to find more information about this interpretation.

For more details, see my answer to What is the Order of the Resurrection of the Dead? - Christianity Stack Exchange.
Briefly:

A small number of people saved during this current age (the elect) will be resurrected as immortal beings at Christ's return.
In the Kingdom of God, here on Earth, they will rule and teach the survivors of the tribulation about God's way of life.
At the end of this Millennium, there will be a second, much larger general resurrection including the vast majority of mankind, where everyone that has died without being offered salvation will be resurrected.
Most people will accept God's way and they too will be reborn as immortal beings.
Finally, the relatively small number that still reject God's holy spirit (the unpardonable sin), will be destroyed.

The first resurrection will be a very small select number of righteous people.
The second resurrection will be a resurrection of righteous and wicked at the same time.
They will be offered salvation for the first time (not a second chance), then judged, then be either reborn or destroyed.
